# Bootstrap: How to access the color variables ("Error: Undefined variable")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Why do I get the following error?

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$red-100"
```

...when I try to use any of Bootstrap's color variables, like so:

```
div {
  background-color: $red-100;
}
```

In my `Gemfile`, I have:

```
gem 'bootstrap'
```

In my `application.scss` file, I have:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

What is missing in order to access these color variables?

EDIT: These color variables are listed in: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

EDIT 2: I use Bootstrap v4.6.0.

Comment: Does it work if you do `@import "bootstrap/variables";` at the top of the scss file where you use $red-100 ?

Comment: @razvans - Unfortunately not, it throws the same error.

Comment: The link in the description is for v5.0.0.beta2. Are you using that version? Here in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/v4.6.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss, there's no $red-100

Comment: @razvans - Thank you so much, that was the issue. I was using v4.6.0... If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can see is that https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss is for `v5.0.0beta2` and probably you are not using that version.

I looked over `v4.6.0`, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/v4.6.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss and `$red-100` does not show up.